# Spark handling small files (coalesce vs CombineFileInputFormat)

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, emr, amazon-emr

I have a use case where I have millions of small files in S3 which needs to be processed by Spark. I have two options to reduce number of tasks:
1. Use Coalesce
2. Extend CombineFileInputFormat

But I'm not clear of performance implications with bot and when to use one over other.

Also, CombineFileInputFormat is an abstract class, that means I need to provide my implementation. But Spark API (newAPIHadoopRDD) takes the class name as param, I'm not sure how to pass configurable maxSplitSize

Answer (score 0):

Another great option to consider for such scenarios is `SparkContext.wholeTextFiles()` which makes one record for each file with its name as the `key` and the content as the `value` -- see [Documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.SparkContext)